# Exception, table not mapped

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

When I run the command in mysql prompt it works properly.

```
SELECT d.lastUpdatedDate,c.phoneNumber1,d.simImea1, d.simImea2,d.model,c.latitude,  c.longitude  from connectionDetails c inner join deviceDetails d  on (c.deviceUniqueIdentity = d.deviceUniqueIdentity AND d.rowStatus='0')
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: connectionDetails is not mapped [SELECT d.lastUpdatedDate,c.phoneNumber1,d.simImea1, d.simImea2,d.model,c.latitude,  c.longitude  from connectionDetails c inner join deviceDetails d  on (c.deviceUniqueIdentity = d.deviceUniqueIdentity AND d.rowStatus='0')]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
```

ConnectionDetails.hbm

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mypackage.CConnectionDetails"
        table="connectionDetails">
        <id name="connectionUniqueIdentity" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="connectionUniqueIdentity" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
```

Edit :

```
Query query = currentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
```

Comment: How are you executing this query from hibernate?

Comment: yes, i am using createQuery. I'll change it to createSQLQuery and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code from

```
Query query = currentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
```

To

```
Query query = currentSession().createQuery(sql);
```

And it worked.